# Cannot convert return expression of type '[()]' to return type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, data-structures

I am using the map to update all array values. But it's returning an empty array.

```
var filterProductList = [CategoryProduct]()
let finalList = filterProductList.map{ p in
            if let pf = test.rankings[0].products.first(where: {$0.id == p.id}) {
                p.rankCount = pf.viewCount
            }
        }
return finalList // Showing error here cannot convert return expression of type '[()]' to return type '[CategoryProduct]'
```

Comment: Nick you got your answer but it's a good practice to provide enough information to your compiler to compile. If you let your compiler to resolve the return type etc. then you build time/compile time will increase over the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly return `p` and to specify the return type

```
let finalList = filterProductList.map{ p -> CategoryProduct in
     if let pf = test.rankings[0].products.first(where: {$0.id == p.id}) {
         p.rankCount = pf.viewCount
     }
     return p
}
```